# How to declare static global values and define them later in Scala?

Tags: scala, oop

#### Primary goal

I want to use some static vals in a class so that I don't have to pass them as function parameters.

### My approach

Since I want them to be static, I am declaring them in the companion object. But I cannot assign them values when I declare them, for some reasons. So I am following the below approach.

```
case class DemoParams(name: String)

class Demo {
  def foo = {
    println("Demo params name is: ", Demo.demoParams.name) // Works fine
    anotherFoo(Demo.demoParams.name)           // Throws NPE !
  }
  def anotherFoo(someName: String) = {
    // some code
  }
}

object Demo {
  var demoParams: DemoParams = _      // Declare here
  def apply() = new Demo()

  def run = {
    demoParams = DemoParams(name = "Salmon")      // Define here
    val demoObj = Demo()
    demoObj.foo
  }

  def main() = {
    run
  }
}

Demo.main()
```

I am able to print `Demo.demoParams` but surprisingly, this throws a NullPointerException when I pass `Demo.demoParams` to another function, while running the Spark app on a cluster.

### Questions

1. Firstly, is this the right way of declaring static values and defining them later? I would prefer to not use vars and use immutable vals. Is there a better alternative?
2. Second, could you think of any reason I would be getting a NPE while passing `Demo.demoParams.name` to another function?

Comment: So you want to mutate something yet make it immutable somehow? - No, what you want to make is impossible and smells like a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Your code [works fine](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LaMWMlcuTMKalhAm9hQY3g) and doesn't throw anything (after fixing a few compile errors).

But ... Don't do this, it's ... yucky :/

How about passing params to the class as ... well ... params instead?

```
case class Demo(params: DemoParams) {
  def foo() = {
    println("Demo params name is: " + params.name) 
  }
}

object Demo {
  def run() = {
    val demoParams = DemoParams(name = "Salmon") 
    val demoObj = Demo(demoParams)
    demoObj.foo()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best alternative, but consider using a `trait`, which still keeps you in the FP zone by avoiding the use of `var`:

```
case class DemoParams(name: String)

trait Demo {
  val demoParams: DemoParams
}
```

Then just define it where you need it, and it's ready for use:

```
object MainApp extends App {
  val demoObj = new Demo {
    override val demoParams: DemoParams = DemoParams(name = "Salmon")
  }

  println("Demo params name is: ", demoObj.demoParams.name) // (Demo params name is: ,Salmon)
  anotherFoo(demoObj.demoParams.name) // Salmon

  def anotherFoo(name: String): Unit = println(name)
}
```

About the second question, without the actual code one can only guess (this sample code does not throw NPE). Probably somewhere you are using it without defining it previously, because `var demoParams: DemoParams = _` just initializes `demoParams` to the default value of the reference type `DemoParams`, which is `null` in this case, and you get NPE when you try to access the `name` value of a `null` object. This is why using `var` is discouraged.